# postgres select cascade references

Tags: postgresql, select, cascade

I have a huge database, with many tables millions of records in production environment. In some cases for bugging tracking and fixing I would like to get a particular main record and all its references and bring them to the development environment. So I can make tests locally before fixing the bug on the production environment.

Its like delete, you cannot delete on record if its referenced by others, unless you use cascade, so all then will be deleted.

I have no use for only the main record, I need it and all others that references it. So I need a select that brings it and all its dependencies.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there's no nice built-in facility for this. You'll likely need to write some plpgsql (or maybe a `WITH RECURSIVE` query) that walks the referential integrity constraint chains in `information_schema`.